# Is it possible to make an action that does line number "x"

Tags: c

Let me explain my self, I don't know if it is possible so i'll write it in pseudo code

```
while (condition)
{
     do the action in line number x;
     x++;
}
```

e.g
if line number 40 in my code contains this following line:
"printf("Hello");"
then the program will print "Hello" and then check the condition and if the condition is true then it will do the action in line number 41.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you need something like `goto`?

Comment: Perhaps if you explain why you want to do this alternatives can be suggested.

Comment: @AlexK. I`m doing an function that check if a password is valid by some parameters(1 Digit at least, 1 lower case letter at least, 1 Upper case letter at least etc..)
and every different parameter is in a function, I want the program to stop if one paramater isn`t valid, and plenty of "if" statement are ugly .

Comment: You can't identify code by line number in C.  You might (perish the thought) use labels; you might use function names; you might use an array of some sort, perhaps function pointers.  You cannot do it by line number per se.

Comment: `switch` is C's combination of integer values and labels.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the idea of `going / jumping to line X, perform and come back`, how about we group some of the *statements*, create some `function`s, call them one-by-one and get our work done? Sounds' cool?

Ok, let me give you the idea of how to do it, you'll write the code. Agree? :-)

1. Take the first requirement [1 digit at least]. write a function, say `int checkForDigit(const char *ip, int size)`, which will check all the elements of the array [upto `size`] and that very moment it finds a digit, it will return 0, otherwise, at the end, return 1.
2. Take the second requirement, [1 small-case letter at least]. write a function, say `int checkForSmallCase(const char *ip, int size)`, which will check all the elements of the array [upto `size`] and that very moment it finds a small-case character, it will return 0, otherwise, at the end, return 1.
3. continue adding separate functions for separate validation needs.

Now, in your code,

1. define one flag variable, and set it to some default value, maybe `-1`.
2. take the input of your password *string*, calculate the size.
3. call the digit checking function with the password string and the length. collect the return value in flag variable.
4. one by one, call all other validating function, and store the return value in flag.

In the end, if all validation are successful, flag will have a value of `0`. Consider the password valid. Otherwise, ask for new password.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm doing an function that check if a password is valid by some parameters(1 Digit at least, 1 lower case letter at least, 1 Upper case letter at least etc..) and every different parameter is in a function, I want the program to stop if one paramater isn't valid and plenty of "if" statement are ugly.

Here is an example on how to do multiple checks without so many `if`statements. To add additional test you just need to add the function and it's error message to the `testfunc`/`errormess` arrays. You don't need to modify the `checkPassword` function at all:

```
int testContainsDigit(char *password);
int testContainsLowerCase(char *password);
int testContainsUppercase(char *password);

int (*testfunc[])(char*) = { testContainsDigit, testContainsLowerCase, testContainsUppercase, NULL };
char *errormess[] = { "Must contain at least one digit", "Must contain lower case character", "Must contain upper case character", NULL };

int checkPassword(char *password) {
    // Apply all checks and print error message for each failed check
    // Return 0 on success, -1 if bad password.
    int goodPassword = 0;
    for (int i = 0; testfunc[i] != NULL; i++) {
        if ((testfunc[i])(password) != 0) {
            printf("%s\n", errormess[i];
            goodPassword = -1;
        }
    }
    return goodPassword;
}
```

Comment: I up clicked this answer because I like the approach, but since this questions is (evidently) from someone new in C, I wonder if function pointers are the best way to address the issue.